# Android gps how to skip distance?

Tags: android, gps, distance, skip

I am working on a GPS-enabled application and I need to record a point each N meters. However, I can't see how I can use onLocationChanged() method in the LocationListener or any other method/class. The onLocationChanged() method gives a point each second, and I need to store each N-meter point.

I believe that this has a simple solution, but since I am beginner in Android, cant find it.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`requestLocationUpdates` has a [minDistance](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)) parameter, that
if I recall correctly does what you want. I haven't been able to test this on a real phone though, so I don't know how accurate it is.

Answer (score 1):

In `onLocationChanged`, compare the location you get with the last one you stored. If it's less than `n` meters, discard it. If not, store it. Rinse. Repeat.

EDIT: Wait, even easier - doesn't `requestLocationUpdates` have a `minDistance` parameter? See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates

Answer (score 0):

it is working perfectly 
myManager = ((LocationManager) ApplicationController.getAppContext().getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE ));
        myManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1 * 1000, 0.00001f, this);

mintime =1000ms always it is calling ....